# $_REQUEST or $_POST phone number value in paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway

How to get buyer phone number in paypal after transaction.

i.e., in return_url or notify_url($_REQUEST or $_POST).

Thanks

Comment: PayPal doesn't even have phone numbers on file for many accounts, and the data is rarely used therefore often may be out of date or even bogus. YOu would have to read the docs to see whether there is a parameter which allows you to request buyer phone number, but don't get your hopes up too high for the data quality :).

Answer (score 3):

You can get the phone number if you make sure that you have settings turn on in your PayPal account . Go to the below url after you login to your PayPal account :

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments

[image]

Once you enable that you will get the phone in IPN as well as on PDT like below which includes phone number too .

IPN Text

```
mc_gross=0.01 &protection_eligibility=Eligible &address_status=confirmed &payer_id=XXXXX&tax=0.00 &address_street=sdfad sfcqa &payment_date=07:32:22 May 05, 2015 PDT &
amp;payment_status=Completed &charset=UTF-8 &address_zip=28202 &first_name=asas &mc_
fee=0.01 &address_country_code=US &address_name=asas sdas &notify_version=3.8 &custo
m= &payer_status=unverified &business=XXXXX&address_country=United State
s &address_city=Charlotte &quantity=1 &verify_sign=ApBHX6qbpxJW-Ll3oP22LSbo0WeuALhKG1yb8
vEI4Ru8T3R32uGwMFbU &payer_email=XXXXXX&**contact_phone=232-321-2345** &txn_id=8
2P55278LK622610P &payment_type=instant &last_name=sdas &address_state=NC &receiver_e
mail=XXXXX&payment_fee=0.01 &receiver_id=XXXXXX&txn_type=web_acc
ept &item_name=Test Item &mc_currency=USD &item_number=123 &residence_country=US &am
p;test_ipn=1 &receipt_id=1673-8486-0790-7009 &handling_amount=0.00 &transaction_subject=
&payment_gross=0.01 &shipping=0.00 &ipn_track_id=6e43b2c5f2c83
```